# Declension for neutral n-nouns (weak noun), (e)s or (e)n?

Tags: noun, declension

My German is currently not good so please use English so I can understand

according to this link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_nouns#Declension_for_case

> II: Personal names, all neuter and most masculine nouns have genitive case -(e)s endings

It said "all neuter" that mean including neutral n-nouns but

> III: Masculine and neuter n-nouns take -(e)n for genitive, dative and accusative

so what exactly is neuter n-nouns in genitive case

Answer (score 2):

I think the Wikipedia page is wrong about point III. According to the German version of the same article

> Anmerkung: Hier gibt es keine Neutra

which is literally saying that in group III there are no neuter nouns.

Comment: This doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: But there is an exception: Das Herz is an n-noun and it is neuter (see http://german.stackexchange.com/a/31685/1487)

Answer (score 1):

You asked »what exactly is neuter n-nouns in genitive case«, and there is exactly one German word that is neuter and an n-noun (all other n-nouns are masculine, and no other neuter noun is an n-noun):

### das Herz

(the heart)

- Singular

  - Nominativ

    > Eines der wichtigsten Organe des Menschen ist **das Herz**.
  - Genitiv

    > Ich spüre das Pochen **des Herzens**.
    >
    > (Only as medical term: Hier befindet sich der Vorhof **des Herzes**.)
  - Dativ

    > Schenke deine Aufmerksamkeit mehr **dem Herzen**.
    >   but also:
    >   Schenke deine Aufmerksamkeit mehr **dem Herz**.
  - Akkusativ

    > Dr. Frankenstein to his servant: »Igor, reiche mir **das Herz** herüber.«
- Plural

  - Nominativ

    > **Die Herzen** der Zuschauer schlugen höher.
  - Genitiv

    > Die Zubereitung **der Herzen** bereitete dem Koch große Freude.
  - Dativ

    > Erich gab **den Herzen** auf seinem Bild eine besonders kräftige Farbe.
  - Akkusativ

    > Seine Rede erreichte **die Herzen** der Zuhörer.

Comment: Isn't das Herz a weak neuter noun?
And with multiple choice endings in the genetive:
Der Schlag meines Herzens/Herzen?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no rule for it, some nouns take `s` others `es` or `ens` or `en`.
they are classified by categories , take a look at the following link:
http://www.dietz-und-daf.de/GD_DkfA/Gramminfo/txt_MII1/Nominal-Flexion%20Q1%20Info.pdf